# How to config Android emulator to connect to internet

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been struggling with how to config my Android emulator to connect to the Internet, and of course I tried a lot of solutions such as disable the `LAN card` or add `dns` server, `http proxy` in eclipse, etc...

Unfortunately, those solutions seem to work very well for lots of people but not for me.

Finally I found the right solution which is easy to understand, easy to do and works well.

Comment: Is this even a question?

Comment: @McGuile. 
I tried to post the answer under the original question but it was protected and I don't have enough reputation to to. So I thought ask a question and post the solution by myself may eventually help someone. But you vote my first question down while I was still typing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reason:
The reason that your PC can connect to internet but your emulator can't is that emulator's default DNS server is [10.0.2.3] which is different from the real one you are currently using.

Steps:
1. 'CMD->ipconfig /all' to get real DNS server e.g. 192.168.1.1
2. 'CMD->adb shell->getprop' to get emulator's DNS info as following
    [net.dns1]:[10.0.2.3]
2. 'CMD->adb shell->setprop net.dns1 192.168.1.1' to set DNS server

note. if adb shell is not recognized as a valid command, try set ANDROID_HOME and path